# What do do about user not following submission rules?

Tags: discussion, rules

There is a user, descheleschilder, who has submitted several images over the last few months and they are breaking the rules. Images typically are not the required 210px tall and they seem to be submitting more than the permitted one image per week. They are fairly decent images and I like to see them among the submissions, but the user needs to be notified. I have left a few size recommendations as comments on the submissions, but there are still numerous more that I didn't comment on and I haven't mentioned the frequency. I currently see eight submissions from the user and only one that meets regulations. Does somebody else want to bring it up as well? Is there a better recommended way of notifying the user? I'm pretty sure they do have the opportunity to alter the size of the ones submitted.

Answer (score 4):

He's updated some of his images and I'm sure he'll resize the rest once he reads the comments.  If not, we would eventually delete the images.  Best way to notify is what you've done - add a comment under the image.  If he responds, fine. If not we just delete after a time.

Answer (score -1):

The requirements are clearly stated.  Moderators should just delete posts that don't comply.